# Change one of params in url with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a path like this

```
/cities/:cityGuid/responses/:responseGuid
```

When a user changes a city, I need to replace `:cityGuid`. For changing city used a `NavLink` component.

```
<NavLink to="current url with changed cityGuid" text="Moscow" />
```

For getting a current url I need to use `location.pathname` and replace a `cityGuid` in this string.

```
current url: /cities/londonCityGuid/responses/abc1
user change city
next url is: /cities/moscowCityGuid/responses/abc1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the full location and change some parameters if you are in a nested route, you can do it with pathToRegexp, url and path from match and pathname from location.

```js
const ParamLink = ({
  children,
  match: { url = '', path = '', params: currentParams = {} } = {},
  location: { pathname = '' } = {},
  params = {}
}) => {
  const urlPartToInsert = pathToRegexp.compile(path)({
    ...currentParams,
    ...params
  });
  const to = pathname.replace(url, urlPartToInsert);
  return <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>;
};

export default ParamLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';

const { match: { path, params } } = this.props;

pathToRegexp.compile(path)({
  ...params,
  cityGuid: 'newCityGuid',
})
```